# Get rid of ugly CustomEditor spacing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been making my own event management system because I don't want to pay money for Playmaker:

[image]

I'm getting this really terrible spacing between labels and their components (for example, in the picture above, between Nickname and it's text field)

The script can be found here (keep in mind, its a work in progress. I haven't had time to clean it all up):

http://pastebin.com/w2cLWBvh

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that layout system you've been using aims to give both the nickname label and text input field nearly the same amount of space within their combined area.

Without knowing an awful lot about what layout options Unity's GUI system has, you can probably do with setting the length of the label and textbox arbitrarily.

Here's how you can get the size of a label given a specific string:

```
GUI.skin.GetStyle("Label").CalcSize(new GUIContent(widestIdString));
```

So say you have a new BeginArea containing your label and textbox combo. You'd set the label length to this newly calculated width, and the textbox width to the difference of the Area's width and the label's width, plus an arbitrary distance to seperate them, such as 23f;